# want to execute a java test class which is in src/test/java from src/main/java but I am unable to import that java class in src/main/java?

Tags: java, maven

In my requirement I need to execute the Junit test class in `src/test/java` from a java class in `src/main/java`, but I am unable to import the java class present in `src/test/java` from `src/main/java`.

Ideally Maven structure also will look forward that main code will be `src/main/java` and test code will be in `src/test/java` and `src/main/java` should not have dependency on `src/test/java`.

but in my case I want to execute Junit class from main program in `src/main/java` but I am unable to import that class from `src/test/java`.

Please provide me any suggestions on how do I can achieve this or is there any way to mention in POM file so that maven allows me to import the class from `src/test/java` in `src/main/java`.

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense. Code in main should not reference code in test.

Comment: simply this is a very bad idea apart from that it will not work..Production code in src/main/java and unit tests in src/test/java that's the way it works...The question is where is such requirement coming from and why? What kind of problem should be solve?

Comment: My code in main is not referencing test but my goal is to run the test class from src/main/java.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an allowed operation. Maven allows you in your Test code to reference all the code in `src/main/java` but not vice versa.

It is semantically incorrect in your production code to rely on something that is available only when testing. In production imagine your test code does not even exist (anything under `src/test/java` would not be available, but `src/main/java` should still work).

If you do need the functionality in your main code, it is advisable to refactor the code somewhere under `src/main/java` and then use it both in the class where you originally needed it, as well as in your test code.

For instance:

```java
// src/main/java
class Production {
    void foo() {
        someTestClass.bar();
    }
}

// src/test/java
class SomeTestClass {
    void testSomething() {
        bar();
    }
    void bar() {
    }
}
```

The above code would not compile, but you could refactor it like so:

```java
// src/main/java
class Production {
    void foo() {
        utility.bar();
    }
}
class Utility {
    void bar() {
    }
}

// src/test/java
class SomeTestClass {
    void testSomething() {
        utility.bar();
    }
}
```

Because the dependency is unidirectional, the code now is available to both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`.

If you want one Maven project's test code to depend on another Maven project's test code, then you should declare the dependecy with scope `test` like this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cool-testing-dependency</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```